# How to transfer voice memos with their titles? (External hard drive, Mac)

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, itunes

I'm trying to get all my voice memo's, with their original name, onto a external hard drive.

(My filenames are all just the date of the recording).

And it's my 3rd evening trying to figure this out facepalm. Remember when we used to be able to just drag and drop this stuff?

(I was able to find [this script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/322284/513001) for Windows, but not sure if there's something similar I could do on a Mac.)