# How to rename voice memos to their titles? (Mac)

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, itunes, high-sierra

I'm trying to get all my voice memo's, with their original name, onto a external hard drive.

(My filenames are all just the date of the recording).

(I was able to find [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198134/how-to-transfer-voice-memo-with-their-titles/322284#322284) script for Windows, but not sure if there's something similar I could do on a Mac)

**More Details:**

I named the memos on my iPhone, in the Voice Memo's app, but when I locate them on my hard drive on my computer, they all have default names that are just the date created.

E.g. 20230405-23234.m4a instead of "Math Lecture April 4 2023.m4a" for example.

And I have 1500+ Voice Memo's which are very important to me, and I need to search through in the future.

Comment: How many voice memos do you have (the solution might be different depending on the number being small or big)? And to get the complete the picture: you renamed the memos on the iPhone, transfered them to the Mac and now they have just a default name?

Comment: @nohillside thanks for your reply - correct, I named the memos on my iPhone, in the Voice Memo's app, but when I locate them on my hard drive on my computer, they all have default names that are just the date created. E.g. 20230405-23234.m4a instead of "Math Lecture April 4 2023.m4a" for example. And I have 1500+ Voice Memo's which are very important to me, and I need to search through in the future.

Comment: please edit the question to add this.

Comment: @nohillside I have updated the post to include these details.

Answer (score -1):

To rename Voice Memos on your Mac, follow these steps:

1. Open the Voice Memos app.
2. Find and select the recording you want to rename.
3. Right-click (or Control-click) on the recording.
4. Choose “Rename” from the context menu.
5. Enter the new name and press Enter.

This should allow you to rename your Voice Memos on your Mac easily.

Comment: No, I mean rename on the computer. They're all saved as strings of numbers (ie. "20230405-2235234.m4a" instead of "Math class April 4 2023.m4a", like I labeled it on my phone.)

I'm trying to create an external backup with all my .m4a files (Voice Memos), so I can access them easily, independent of 3rd party tools like iTunes, etc.